# C - Doubly Linked List always null

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am writting a program on doubly linked list with the following data structure:

```
typedef struct telephoneBookNode {
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char telephone[TELEPHONE_LENGTH];
    struct telephoneBookNode * previousNode;
    struct telephoneBookNode * nextNode;
} TelephoneBookNode;

typedef struct telephoneBookList {
    TelephoneBookNode * head;
    TelephoneBookNode * tail;
    TelephoneBookNode * current;
} TelephoneBookList;
```

In the following function, I read data from a text file to the linked list, the file content look like this:

```
/*100, Alice, 0411112222
101, Bob, 0411112222
102, Ali, 0411112223*/

TelephoneBookList * commandLoad(char* fileName) {
    TelephoneBookList *(*createList)(TelephoneBookNode*, char[]) = createTelephoneBookList;

    char entry[100], *temp1, *temp2;
    TelephoneBookList* aList = NULL;
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode = NULL;
    FILE* telephoneListFile = NULL;
    int countEntry = 0;
    Boolean check;

    telephoneListFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!telephoneListFile)
        return NULL;
    else {
        while (fgets(entry, 100, telephoneListFile)) {
            temp2 = strcpy(temp2, entry);
            temp1 = strtok(entry, "\n");
            check = addressBookEntryCheck(temp1);

            if (!check)
                return NULL;
            else
                //here I pass aNode pointer to the below function
                aList = (*createList)(aNode, temp2);
        }
        fclose(telephoneListFile);
        printf("printed"); //This line is reached when program complied
        return aList;
    }
}
```

This is the function to create the list, problem may be here: it doesnot add new node to the list, it just replaces the first node with the new one. Finally, the linked list only has 1 record which was the last one in text file. How can I fix the code? Thank you!

```
TelephoneBookList * createTelephoneBookList(TelephoneBookNode* node, char entry[]) {
    TelephoneBookList* aList = malloc(sizeof *aList);
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode = (TelephoneBookNode*) malloc(sizeof *aNode);
    char *tokens;

    tokens = strtok(entry, ", ");
    aNode->id = atoi(tokens);

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    strcpy(aNode->name, tokens);

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    strcpy(aNode->telephone, tokens); //Just assigning values to a node

    //program always go to this block, means `node` is always null
    if (node == NULL) {
        aNode->nextNode = NULL;
        aNode->previousNode = NULL;
        node = aNode;

        aList->current = node;
        aList->head = node;
        aList->tail = node;
    }
    else { //This block is not reached
        while (node->nextNode)
            node = node->nextNode;

        node->nextNode = aNode;
        aNode->previousNode = node;

        aList->tail = node->nextNode;
    }
    return aList;
}
```

This is the function to check entry:

```
Boolean addressBookEntryCheck(char entry[]) {
    char *tokens;

    tokens = strtok(entry, ", ");

    if(!tokens || strlen(tokens) < 1 || strlen(tokens) > 3)
        return FALSE;
    else {
        if (!isNumber(tokens))
            return FALSE;
        else {
            tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");

            if (!tokens)
                return FALSE;
            else
            {
                tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");

                if (!tokens)
                    return FALSE;
                else if (!isNumber(tokens) || strlen(tokens) != 10)
                    return FALSE;
                else
                    return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `node = ...` is meaningless to the *caller* of your function. That pointer is passed by value (all your changing is an automatic local var once inside the function).

Comment: how does `addressBookEntryCheck` look like? If it always returns true you will get the behavior you described. If I were you I would make the function do a little less to make it easier to follow i.e. one function to create the list header, one to add nodes.

Comment: I have added the function `addressBookEntryCheck`, it always returns `false` actually, even nothing wrong with entry format.

Comment: I try many ways but the program always return a null list, really dont know how to fix it

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: I forgot how to use debug tool in eclipse. actually I do the program in Unix, I use `gdb` command to trace but got not much detail

Comment: for one thing this is suspicious `temp2 = strcpy(temp2, entry);` what does temp2 point to in the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call

```
createTelephoneBookList
```

you create a new list

```
TelephoneBookList* aList = malloc(sizeof *aList);
```

You also copy to an uninitialized pointer

```
temp2 = strcpy(temp2, entry);
```

I would suggest you create one function to create the list header, one function to add new items e.g.

```
aList = createList()
while (fgets(entry,sizeof(entry),fp)!=NULL)
{
  if (!addEntry(aList,entry))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed additem item %s\n", entry);
  }
}
...
```

In addEntry parse the string

```
int id = 0;
char name[NAME_LENGTH];
char telephone[TELEPHONE_LENGTH];

p = strtok(entry, ","); // id
if (p != NULL) 
{  
  id = atoi(p);
  p = strtok(NULL, ","); // name, store to temporary string
  if (p != NULL )
  {
    strcpy(name,p);
    p = strtok(NULL, ","); // telephone number, store to temporary string
    if ( p != NULL )
    {
      strcpy(telephone,p);

      // here you can allocate the new node
    }
  }
}

// disclaimer omitted checks for length etc which any good program should have. also make sure you have room for \0
```

if any of the `strtok` above fail return 0 otherwise allocate a new entry

```
TelephoneBookNode* aNode = malloc(sizeof(TelephoneBookNode));
aNode->id = id;
strcpy(aNode->name, name); 
strcpy(aNode->telephone, telephone);
```

Then add to your `aList`

Answer (score 0):

```
//program always go to this block, means `node` is always null
    if (node == NULL) {
    ....
```

This is because the caller of the function passed `aNode` and it never changes within that loop. So it will always pass same value of `aNode` which is `NULL`.

I haven't looked at the logic of your code in details, but I think you may want to pass `aList->head` or rather you already pass `aList` so just use that.